# Twisted non default root HTTP

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

1. So I want to have all of the urls start with "/files".
2. The rootpage located at "localhost:3000/files" will return a list of specific folders that will be shared. The default share does not let me limit what folders to share.
3. I want to show all of the files in the folder when navigated to a folder. With the URL like "localhost:3000/files/Documents".
4. I want to share the specific folders and files in the folders recursively. With the URL like "localhost:3000/files/Documents/Filename.pdf".

   ```
   from twisted.web.server import Site
   from twisted.web.resource import Resource
   from twisted.web.static import File
   from twisted.internet import reactor

   folder_list = ["Documents", "Downloads"]


   class RootPage(Resource):
       isLeaf = True
       def render_GET(self, request):
           print request.uri
           new_request = request.uri[7:]
           if len(new_request) <= 3:
               ret = ""
               for folders in folder_list:
                   ret += "<a href='%s'>%s</a></br>" % ("/files/" + folders.replace(" ", "-") , folders)
               return ret

   root = Resource()            
   #folders
   root.putChild('files', RootPage())

   for folders in folder_list:
       root.putChild( folders.replace(" ", "-"), File("/home/user1/" + folders))

   factory = Site(root)

   reactor.listenTCP(3000, factory)
   reactor.run()
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problems

1) In the `.putChild()` call, you establish your folder URLs as children of the root, not children of `/files`.

2) In the `RootPage` class definition, you set `isLeaf` to `True`. But you are creating an interior node, not a leaf node.

---

## Solution

Delete the `isLeaf` line, and change the other relevant lines to this:

```
root = Resource()
rootpage = RootPage()
#folders
root.putChild('files', rootpage)

for folders in folder_list:
    rootpage.putChild( folders.replace(" ", "-"), File("/home/user1/" + folders))

factory = Site(root)
```